# How to vendor all packages in go project

Tags: go, govendor

I cloned a project from Github whose dependencies aren't vendored. Typically, running `go get ./...` in the project directory should install all dependencies. However i am using [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor) and i would like all dependencies to show up in my vendor folder. Usually i would run `govendor init` to create the `vendor` folder, Then `govendor fetch github.com/some/dependency` for all my dependencies.

Is there a single `govendor` command that would simulate `go get ./...`? `govendor get ./...` doesn't work.

Comment: purely a gopher to gopher comment, migrating to dep will solve this problem automatically as `dep init` creates the vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor/blob/master/doc/faq.md):

> Q: How do I populate the vendor folder if it has not been checked in?
>
> A: Run govendor sync.